# How to convert a text object directly to an ngon?

Tags: conversion, text-object

Is there a way to convert a text object directly into an Ngon?

Very often when using text it's necessary to convert it to a mesh for further manipulation. However, the resulting mesh is full of triangles and generally a mess.  It would be ideal to simply have a resulting Ngon since it is a flat plane anyway.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136/svg-to-mesh-conversion/185#185, and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3020/how-to-prevent-triangulation-of-models-when-importing-models-from-sketchup-to-bl

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No**. But there is another way to achieve it.

1. Select the mesh and hit Spacebar to invoke the function search menu.
2. Search for *limited dissolve* and initiate it. You can change the parameters by hitting <kbd>F6</kbd>.

[image: Cleaner fonts]

Also note:

- After you do a limited dissolve there may still be some manual cleaning up to do.
- Limited dissolve is also in the *Delete menu* accessible with <kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd>
- Limited dissolve is the same as the *Planar* setting in the [*Decimate* modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html), so this can be done non-destructively
- Blender does not support N-gons with holes in them. you will have to have a split along it somewhere.
- If the n-gon is not co-planar you may see artifacts.

Comment: *Limited dissolve* is also in the *Delete* menu accessible with `X` and the `Delete` key. Also maybe add a note that *Limited dissolve* is the same as the *Planar* setting in the *Decimate modifier*, so this can be done non-destructively.